# Exception with REST implementation with jersey

Tags: json, rest, exception, jersey

I am building a REST service with jersey and I am stuck with a weird exception.
I want to hit a REST uri similar to:

```
http://localhost:9889/rest/Users/{userid}
```

the content to be sent with the request is in JSON similar to:

```
{
"attr1":"name",
"attr2":"age"
}
```

The endpoint url code is as shwon below:

```
@Path("/rest/Users")
class Users
{
        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        @Path("/{userId}")
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public String getUserInfoQuery(

            QueryDoc reqJSON,

            @PathParam("userId") String userId,

            @HeaderParam("Session-Token") String sessionId,

            @HeaderParam("Authorization") String authToken) 
    )
    {
    .
    .
    .
    .
    }
}
```

And QueryDoc resource looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class QueryDoc
{

@XmlElement(name = "attr1")
private String attr1;


    @XmlElement(name = "attr2")
    private String attr2;
   //getters and setters
.
.
.
.

}
```

When I am starting the server, an exception is thrown

```
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: Fatal issues found at
class com.test.Users. See logs for more details.
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.newResourceClass(WebApplicationIm....
```

I could find this exception here http://www.skybert.net/java/jersey/
and as mentioned in this link..the reason is

```
 public String getUserInfoQuery(

            QueryDoc reqJSON,
```

reqJSON is not being annotated. If I annotate it with some annotation the exception is not thrown when server is started but in this case url response is meaningless. If i remove this parameter the url works but it doesn't consume the request JSON.
How can I make it work where I want to consume JSON content of the request as well as HeaderParams and PathParams

Comment: Look for "SEVERE" error it prints to the log before you get the above exception. Update your question with that error.

Answer (score 2):

Is your getUserInfoQuery() method annotated with @GET annotation? If so, it is mapped to HTTP GET request. You cannot send entity in HTTP GET, so the unannotated parameter does not make sense (as Jersey maps entity to the unannotated param, but as said, in case of GET there is no entity).

Answer (score 1):

Change your method `getUserInfoQuery()` to `@PUT`. 
 In the `QueryDoc` class remove all annotations except `@XmlRootElement`. Since the attribute name you pass in the request body is same as the those in `QueryDoc` `@XmlElement` is not required. Moreover `@XmlElement` should be given to ge getter method.
This is a [good article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html) on ReST with Jersey.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

I had the same exception with no additional details on Jersey's 'newResourceClass' method; 
after hours of debugging, I realized it happened due to ambiguous URIs.

Check your URIs and eliminate any possible duplicates, such as this one:

```
@Path("/users")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<String> getUsers() {
    ...
}

@Path("/users") // BAD
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getUserById(@QueryParam("userId") String userId) {
    ...
}
```